# Series Radius of Convergence (Absolute)

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\left(\frac{n+1}{n^2}\right)x^n.
$$
Find the real numbers $x$ for which the series $(i)$ converges and $(ii)$ absolutely converges.

I did the ratio test and found radius of convergence to be $1$. I checked endpoints and I ended up with $x \in (-1,1]$. I believe this is correct but I might be wrong. I know this is the set of values of $x$ for which the series absolutely converges so is the answer to $(ii)$.

So for $(i)$ what would I do. I know if a series is absolutely convergent then it is convergent, so would the answer be the same? My other thought was to when doing $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ to drop the absolute values. Either way I end up with the same answer so would this be the difference in working out I would have to show ?

Answer (score 2):

For $x = 1$, the series converges by the alternating series test, but does not converge absolutely by comparison with $\sum_n 1/n$.  For $x = -1$, it neither converges nor converges absolutely.  So $(-1,1]$ is the answer to (i) and $(-1,1)$ is the answer to (ii).

Comment: Thanks @RobertIsrael . So just to confirm for both when taking $a_{n+1}$ over $a_n$, am I allowed to take the absolute value for absolute convergence in $(ii)$ and not in $(i)$. And then proceed like you said ? Cheers.

Comment: because in that instance I end up with $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=-1$, so $R=-1$. Or would I keep the absolute values to get $R=1$ and when checking endpoints drop the absolute values ?

Comment: You can use absolute values in the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).  But this will have inconclusive results for the end points, and can never distinguish between absolute convergence and non-absolute convergence. You need more sensitive tests.  In this case, as I said, the alternating series test and a comparison test.

Comment: Okay thanks. We were never taught that so I appreciate it.

Comment: If the question just says find the values for which the power series converges, then we ignore absolute convergence right ? I was confused because I thought absolute convergence -> convergence